# Network Analysis for Pickup and Dropoff

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, pgrouting, network-analyst, reverse-geocoding

I have a bit of a problem that I need help with. I am looking at a set of lat/long with a time stamp for the desired pickup or drop-off for passengers. There are multiple pick-ups and drop-offs within a service area that has these attributes. On top of that I need to be able to allow for picking up one passenger and then pickup another, while allowing for the shortest time-frame (distance to keep it simple) for drop-off at desired locations. In other words, there are multiple dropoff and pickup locations, and I want to maximize efficiency in scheduling these with the desired time, some flexibility (10min. + or -).  I am thinking that I would need to use pg_Routing (or similar) in QGIS or the Network analyst extension in arcgis, but I have limited experience in these and was wondering what the best approach might be to tackling such a task. Is this possible with these tools?

Comment: I would use VRP solver for this since you have NA extension for ArcGIS.http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00470000004v000000

Comment: Here's a great talk on PGRouting (routing extension for PostGIS / PostgreSQL) that really communicated to me the capability and potential for PGRouting... I've got a project in mind for a friend similar to yours that I will be setting up on PGRouting...

Comment: Network Analyst should be able to handle it and so is our FleetEngine product (see www.routeware.dk). pgRouting isn't able to do it.